Argument to solving $u_{xx}-3u_{xt}-4u_{tt}=0$
When solving the PDE:
\begin{align*}
u_{xx}-3u_{xt}-4u_{tt}=0
\end{align*}
Is the following idea correct: Factor the PDE as $(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial}{\partial t})(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}-4\frac{\partial}{\partial t})u=0$. Then i can independently solve $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}-4\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=0$ and $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=0$ by some method, the result is the sum of the two solutions. The course literature i have says something like: let $v = u_x + u_t$. Then we get
\begin{align*}
& v_x - 4v_t = 0 \\
& u_x + u_t = v
\end{align*}
I get the same result and the first method is for me atleast easier. Is there something wrong with it?

General solution: $u(x,t)=f_1(t-x)+f_2(t+4x)$

Using the superposition principle to combine the solutions to the two first order equations in your method requires that the PDE is linear an homogeneous.  The given second order PDE is linear and homogeneous, but the method from the course materials works when that is not the case.
Let's look at your factored form
$$  (\partial_x + \partial_t)(\partial_x - 4 \partial_t)u = 0  $$
This says "apply $(\partial_x - 4 \partial_t)$ to $u$, then apply $(\partial_x + \partial_t)$ to that, arriving at zero".  You're method ignores the two applications, which is fine when superposition applies.  However, when that is not the case, it is better to think "Solve $(\partial_x + \partial_t)v = 0$ where $v = (\partial_x - 4 \partial_t)u$", which includes the chained applications (and is the other way to order the factors for the method from the course materials).
